# homomorphism question

Tags: linear-algebra, ring-homomorphism

Check $p(x) + p(-x) ∈ P^e$   for every   $p(x) ∈ \mathbb{R}[x]$. Check that the map $Ψ:\mathbb{R}[x]\to P^e$ given by $Ψ(p(x))=(p(x)+p(-x))/2$ is a linear map. Further check that $Ψ^2=Ψ$. Determine the kernel of $Ψ$.

Comment: What is $P^e$? ...

Comment: Is it $Ψ$ correctly defined?

Comment: Surely you can answer some of these questions right?

Comment: $p(x)\in R(x)$, don't you mean $p(x)\in R[x]$ ?

Comment: i need its answer guys ...its urgent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that 
$$
P^e = \left\{ p(x) \in \mathbb{R}[X] \ \middle| \ p(x)=p(-x) \right\}
$$
is the set of even polynomials.

For a $p(x) \in \mathbb{R}[X]$, define $f_p(x)=p(x)+p(-x)$. We calculate
$$
f_p(-x) = p(-x)+p(x) = p(x)+p(-x) = f_p(x)
$$
and thus $f_p(x) \in P^e$ for every $p(x)$. This implies that $\Psi \colon \mathbb{R}[X] \to P^e$ is well defined.

We check linearity as follows: Let $p(x),q(x) \in \mathbb{R}[X]$, then
\begin{align*}
  \Psi (p(x)+q(x)) &= \frac{p(x)+q(x)+p(-x)+q(-x)}{2} \\
&= \frac{p(x)+p(-x)}{2} + \frac{q(x)+q(-x)}{2} = \Psi (p(x)) + \Psi (q(x))
\end{align*}
and for $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$,
$$
\Psi(\lambda p(x)) = \frac{\lambda p(x) + \lambda p(-x) }{2} = \lambda \frac{p(x)+p(-x)}{2} = \lambda \Psi (p(x))
$$
which concludes the proof of the linearity.

We calculate
$$
\Psi (\Psi (p(x))) = \Psi \left( \frac{p(x)+p(-x)}{2}\right) = \frac{\frac{p(x)+p(-x)}{2} + \frac{p(-x)+p(x)}{2}}{2} = \frac{p(x)+p(-x)}{2} = \Psi(p(x)),
$$
i.e. $\Psi ^2 = \Psi$.

Finally $\Psi (p(x)) = \frac{p(x)+p(-x)}{2} = 0$, if and only if $p(x)+p(-x) =0$, so 
$$
\ker \Psi = \left\{ p(x) \in \mathbb{R}[X] \ \middle|\ p(-x)=-p(x) \right\},
$$
i.e. the kernel of $\Psi$ is the set of odd polynomials.

Comment: thank you very much :)